# People can see me when I should be invisible! What do I do?

Tags: dota-2

Frequently, while playing as a hero that relies on invisibility (such as Broodmother), there comes a point in the game where I *should* be invisible, yet people walk right up to me and attack me anyway.

How do they do this and how can I counter it?

Comment: [Dota 2 Wiki "True Sight"](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/True_Sight) is probably the most encompassing explanation. Just leaving this here if anyone wants to turn it into an answer.

Comment: [Maybe you should put some shorts on or something...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mzWN4v2Ck0s)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Several items or skills in the game reveal invisible units. Here is a list and few tips on how to counter the problem :

**Items**

- [Dust of Appearance](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Dust) : purge yourself [Eul's Scepter](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Eul%27s_Scepter_of_Divinity). [Manta Style](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Manta_Style) also dispels dust.
- [Sentry Ward](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Sentry) : get a Gem or your own sentries to deward.
- [Gem of True Sight](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Gem_of_True_Sight) : gank the carrier.
- [Necronomicon (level 3)](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Necronomicon) : kill the Necronomicon units but keep in mind that the ability "Last will" from Necronomicon units level 3 will deal 800 magical damage to the killer.

**Skills**

- [Thirst (Bloodseeker)](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Bloodseeker#Thirst) : not much you can do except run.
- [Amplify damage (Slardar)](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Slardar#Amplify_Damage) : you can purge yourself with Eul's or use Manta Style.
- [Track (Bounty Hunter)](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Bounty_Hunter) : you can purge yourself with Eul's or use Manta Style.
- [Lightning bolt and Thundergod's Wrath (Zeus)](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Zeus) : not much you can do except run.

**Extra Information**

Always be aware that the enemy team will sooner or later get a way to detect you. By checking regularly the enemy's heroes inventories and looking for detection items, you can avoid a lot of unfortunate deaths.

Comment: Or, avoid the pain all together and just don't play heroes that rely on invis.  If the other team is good they *will* see you and with anything less than a pro team you won't counter it -- rendering your invis useless so there goes one skill slot that, on another hero, will have better perks associated with it.  Needless to say you don't see Riki played competitively for exactly this reason.

Comment: @DavidCowden I disagree, heroes such as Gondar, Weaver, Phantom Lancer or heroes rushing Shadow blade such as Alchemist or Nature's Prophet are a part of the current metagme

Comment: @WizLiz Buying an invisibility item on a hero that already has invisibility will get you absolutely ridiculed. On Alchemist+NP it's fine, but absolutely not on Rikimaru or Broodmother (who are Agility heroes and thus have better DPS item options). They should be buying Diffusal Blade or Manta to dispel silences if absolutely necessary.

Comment: @WizLiz I'm not talking about heroes that have useful invis spells, but Riki is a particularly good example of a wasted skill slot.  Heroes that *rely* on invis work primarily in pubs where teams are not organized.  I'm not saying they're useless -- far from it.  But people often fall into the trap of *relying* on invis when they could be ramping up dps or other, *imho*, more useful attributes/items.

Comment: @Decency Yes I agree. I was going to mention low level pub play but they rarely use silence to dispell invis on rikimaru

Comment: @DavidCowden Sure totaly agree, and riki is extremely hard to play when you start facing good players. Its really difficult to no become absolutely useless for the team