# What self-spells or allied-spells can break riki's invisibility

Tags: dota-2

Riki is an effective hero to play against new players. My problem is that sometimes I'm afraid to use some spells because I'm not sure if I will get visible. Examples:

- magic stick
- changing attribute in power treads
- teleport
- urn
- diffusal blade

Can any teammate make me visible when buffing me? Examples:

- ogre magi
- lich
- legion commander
- urn

Comment: Worth noting is that this behavior changed very recently, in [v6.79](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/dota2/index.php?title=Riki#Version_History)

Comment: Was any answer helpfull ? If so don't forget to tick it so future user can know, if not don't hesistate to tell what was wrong with it so people can edit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Riki is not revealed out of Permanent Invisibility when he casts spells or uses items. (Including dagon)
- Gettings buffs from teammates won't reveal any invisible heroes.
- Getting silenced (even if they don't see you) will reveal you.

You only get revealed when you are attacking or when you are near someone with true sight.

Comment: You can add that also Void Chronophere make him visible and technically is not a Silence.

Comment: Technically it is :)  Ever seen anyone cast spells from the chronosphere?

Comment: It's a pause effect in DotA1 i believe.

Comment: what about sven's stun? you get stunned/damaged but not revealed?

Comment: yes, check out this: http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Invis

Answer (score 1):

The only ways to get revealed are either :

- From the enemy team : True sight or being silenced ([See my previous post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132372/people-can-see-me-when-i-should-be-invisible-what-do-i-do/132383#132383))
- From you : Attacking

You won't break invis by casting a spell or using an item (even changing power tread attribute). Being buffed by an ally won't break invis either. However it will make your presence quite obvious for the enemy team : You don't see often an Ogre magi cast Blood lust in the wind.

Note that any invis hero can be buffed by an ally (gondar while shadow walk, clinkz's ghost walk or anyone whith shadow blade) without being revlead aswell.

Comment: what about smoke in riki? death pact in clinkz? is this considered attack?

Comment: I dont understand your question : using smoke is not considered an attack so you wont get revealed. Attacking in smoke however will reveal you. Rikimaru is the ONLY hero with the invisibility that doesnt break upon cating a spell so if clinkz cast death pact he will reveal.

Comment: ok. thanks. I just was pretty sure that riki gets revealed when using smoke, so i tried to understand if this belongs to the "attacking" case of being revealed.

Comment: Nop, Attacking is really right clicking your opponent, smoke is a spell.